# Service-Unavailable(503) Error in Smack XEP-0198: Stream Management

Tags: xmpp, smack, stream-management

I am using below class to enable stream management("urn:xmpp:sm:3") in our ejabberd server(we have latest version of ejabberd). But when I send the Enable packet to server it says Service Unavailable(503). But when I use "yaxim" it works perfectly. Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks.

```
    public class XmppStreamHandler {
        public static final String URN_SM_3 = "urn:xmpp:sm:3";
        private static final int MAX_OUTGOING_QUEUE_SIZE = 20;
        private static final int OUTGOING_FILL_RATIO = 4;
        private XMPPConnection mConnection;
        private boolean isSmAvailable = false;
        private boolean isSmEnabled = false;
        private boolean isOutgoingSmEnabled = false;
        private long previousIncomingStanzaCount = -1;
        private String sessionId;
        private long incomingStanzaCount = 0;
        private long outgoingStanzaCount = 0;
        private Queue<Packet> outgoingQueue;
        private int maxOutgoingQueueSize = MAX_OUTGOING_QUEUE_SIZE;
        private ConnectionListener mConnectionListener;

        public XmppStreamHandler(XMPPConnection connection, ConnectionListener connectionListener) {
            mConnection = connection;
            mConnectionListener = connectionListener;
            startListening();
        }

        /** Perform a quick shutdown of the XMPPConnection if a resume is possible */
        public void quickShutdown() {
            if (isResumePossible()) {
                mConnection.quickShutdown();
                // We will not necessarily get any notification from a quickShutdown, so adjust our state here.
                closeOnError();
            } else {
                mConnection.shutdown();
            }
        }

        public void setMaxOutgoingQueueSize(int maxOutgoingQueueSize) {
            this.maxOutgoingQueueSize = maxOutgoingQueueSize;
        }

        public boolean isResumePossible() {
            return sessionId != null;
        }

        public boolean isResumePending() {
            return isResumePossible() && !isSmEnabled;
        }

        public static void addExtensionProviders() {
            addSimplePacketExtension("sm", URN_SM_3);
            addSimplePacketExtension("r", URN_SM_3);
            addSimplePacketExtension("a", URN_SM_3);
            addSimplePacketExtension("enabled", URN_SM_3);
            addSimplePacketExtension("resumed", URN_SM_3);
            addSimplePacketExtension("failed", URN_SM_3);

        }

        public void notifyInitialLogin() {
            if (sessionId == null && isSmAvailable)
                sendEnablePacket();
        }

        private void sendEnablePacket() {
            debug("sm send enable " + sessionId);
            if (sessionId != null) {
                isOutgoingSmEnabled = true;
                // TODO binding
                StreamHandlingPacket resumePacket = new StreamHandlingPacket("resume", URN_SM_3);
                resumePacket.addAttribute("h", String.valueOf(previousIncomingStanzaCount));
                resumePacket.addAttribute("previd", sessionId);
                mConnection.sendPacket(resumePacket);
            } else {
                outgoingStanzaCount = 0;
                outgoingQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Packet>();
                isOutgoingSmEnabled = true;

                StreamHandlingPacket enablePacket = new StreamHandlingPacket("enable", URN_SM_3);
                enablePacket.addAttribute("resume", "true");
                mConnection.sendPacket(enablePacket);
            }
        }

        private void closeOnError() {
            if (isSmEnabled && sessionId != null) {
                previousIncomingStanzaCount = incomingStanzaCount;
            }
            isSmEnabled = false;
            isOutgoingSmEnabled = false;
            isSmAvailable = false;
        }

        private void startListening() {
            mConnection.forceAddConnectionListener(new ConnectionListener() {
                public void reconnectionSuccessful() {
                }

                public void reconnectionFailed(Exception e) {
                }

                public void reconnectingIn(int seconds) {
                }

                public void connectionClosedOnError(Exception e) {
                    if (e instanceof XMPPException &&
                            ((XMPPException)e).getStreamError() != null) {
                        // Non-resumable stream error
                        close();
                    } else {
                        // Resumable
                        closeOnError();
                    }
                }

                public void connectionClosed() {
                    previousIncomingStanzaCount = -1;
                }
            });

            mConnection.addPacketSendingListener(new PacketListener() {
                public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
                    // Ignore our own request for acks - they are not counted
                    if (!isStanza(packet)) {
                        trace("send " + packet.toXML());
                        return;
                    }

                    if (isOutgoingSmEnabled && !outgoingQueue.contains(packet)) {
                        outgoingStanzaCount++;
                        outgoingQueue.add(packet);

                        trace("send " + outgoingStanzaCount + " : " + packet.toXML());

                        // Don't let the queue grow beyond max size.  Request acks and drop old packets
                        // if acks are not coming.
                        if (outgoingQueue.size() >= maxOutgoingQueueSize / OUTGOING_FILL_RATIO) {
                            mConnection.sendPacket(new StreamHandlingPacket("r", URN_SM_3));
                        }

                        if (outgoingQueue.size() > maxOutgoingQueueSize) {
    //                        Log.e(XmppConnection.TAG, "not receiving acks?  outgoing queue full");
                            outgoingQueue.remove();
                        }
                    } else if (isOutgoingSmEnabled && outgoingQueue.contains(packet)) {
                        outgoingStanzaCount++;
                        trace("send DUPLICATE " + outgoingStanzaCount + " : " + packet.toXML());
                    } else {
                        trace("send " + packet.toXML());
                    }
                }
            }, new PacketFilter() {
                public boolean accept(Packet packet) {
                    return true;
                }
            });

            mConnection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {
                public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
                    if (isSmEnabled && isStanza(packet)) {
                        incomingStanzaCount++;
                        trace("recv " + incomingStanzaCount + " : " + packet.toXML());
                    } else {
                        trace("recv " + packet.toXML());
                    }

                    if (packet instanceof StreamHandlingPacket) {
                        StreamHandlingPacket shPacket = (StreamHandlingPacket) packet;
                        String name = shPacket.getElementName();
                        if ("sm".equals(name)) {
                            debug("sm avail");
                            isSmAvailable = true;
                            if (sessionId != null)
                                sendEnablePacket();
                        } else if ("r".equals(name)) {
                            StreamHandlingPacket ackPacket = new StreamHandlingPacket("a", URN_SM_3);
                            ackPacket.addAttribute("h", String.valueOf(incomingStanzaCount));
                            mConnection.sendPacket(ackPacket);
                        } else if ("a".equals(name)) {
                            long ackCount = Long.valueOf(shPacket.getAttribute("h"));
                            removeOutgoingAcked(ackCount);
                            trace(outgoingQueue.size() + " in outgoing queue after ack");
                        } else if ("enabled".equals(name)) {
                            incomingStanzaCount = 0;
                            isSmEnabled = true;
                            mConnection.getRoster().setOfflineOnError(false);
                            String resume = shPacket.getAttribute("resume");
                            if ("true".equals(resume) || "1".equals(resume)) {
                                sessionId = shPacket.getAttribute("id");
                            }
                            debug("sm enabled " + sessionId);
                        } else if ("resumed".equals(name)) {
                            debug("sm resumed");
                            incomingStanzaCount = previousIncomingStanzaCount;
                            long resumeStanzaCount = Long.valueOf(shPacket.getAttribute("h"));
                            // Removed acked packets
                            removeOutgoingAcked(resumeStanzaCount);
                            trace(outgoingQueue.size() + " in outgoing queue after resume");

                            // Resend any unacked packets
                            for (Packet resendPacket : outgoingQueue) {
                                mConnection.sendPacket(resendPacket);
                            }

                            // Enable only after resend, so that the interceptor does not
                            // queue these again or increment outgoingStanzaCount.
                            isSmEnabled = true;

                            // Re-notify the listener - we are really ready for packets now
                            // Before this point, isSuspendPending() was true, and the listener should have
                            // ignored reconnectionSuccessful() from XMPPConnection.
                            mConnectionListener.reconnectionSuccessful();
                        } else if ("failed".equals(name)) {
                            // Failed, shutdown and the parent will retry
                            debug("sm failed");
                            mConnection.getRoster().setOfflineOnError(true);
                            mConnection.getRoster().setOfflinePresences();
                            sessionId = null;
                            mConnection.shutdown();
                            // isSmEnabled / isOutgoingSmEnabled are already false
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, new PacketFilter() {
                public boolean accept(Packet packet) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }


        private void removeOutgoingAcked(long ackCount) {
            if (ackCount > outgoingStanzaCount) {
    //            Log.e(XmppConnection.TAG,
    //                    "got ack of " + ackCount + " but only sent " + outgoingStanzaCount);
                // Reset the outgoing count here in a feeble attempt to re-sync.  All bets
                // are off.
                outgoingStanzaCount = ackCount;
            }

            int size = outgoingQueue.size();
            while (size > outgoingStanzaCount - ackCount) {
                outgoingQueue.remove();
                size--;
            }
        }

        private static void addSimplePacketExtension(final String name, final String namespace) {
            ProviderManager.getInstance().addExtensionProvider(name, namespace,
                    new PacketExtensionProvider() {
                        public PacketExtension parseExtension(XmlPullParser parser) throws Exception {
                            StreamHandlingPacket packet = new StreamHandlingPacket(name, namespace);
                            int attributeCount = parser.getAttributeCount();
                            for (int i = 0; i < attributeCount; i++) {
                                packet.addAttribute(parser.getAttributeName(i),
                                        parser.getAttributeValue(i));
                            }
                            return packet;
                        }
                    });
        }

        private void debug(String message) {
            System.out.println(message);
        }

        private void trace(String message) {
            System.out.println(message);
        }

        public static class StreamHandlingPacket extends UnknownPacket {
            private String name;
            private String namespace;
            Map<String, String> attributes;

            StreamHandlingPacket(String name, String namespace) {
                this.name = name;
                this.namespace = namespace;
                attributes = Collections.emptyMap();
            }

            public void addAttribute(String name, String value) {
                if (attributes == Collections.EMPTY_MAP)
                    attributes = new HashMap<String, String>();
                attributes.put(name, value);
            }

            public String getAttribute(String name) {
                return attributes.get(name);
            }

            public String getNamespace() {
                return namespace;
            }

            public String getElementName() {
                return name;
            }

            public String toXML() {
                StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
                buf.append("<").append(getElementName());

                // TODO Xmlns??
                if (getNamespace() != null) {
                    buf.append(" xmlns=\"").append(getNamespace()).append("\"");
                }
                for (String key : attributes.keySet()) {
                    buf.append(" ").append(key).append("=\"")
                            .append(StringUtils.escapeForXML(attributes.get(key))).append("\"");
                }
                buf.append("/>");
                return buf.toString();
            }

        }

        /** Returns true if the packet is a Stanza as defined in RFC-6121 - a Message, IQ or Presence packet. */
        public static boolean isStanza(Packet packet) {
            if (packet instanceof Message)
                return true;
            if (packet instanceof IQ)
                return true;
            if (packet instanceof Presence)
                return true;
            return false;
        }

        public void queue(Packet packet) {
            if (outgoingQueue.size() >= maxOutgoingQueueSize) {
                System.out.println("outgoing queue full");
                return;
            }
            outgoingStanzaCount++;
            outgoingQueue.add(packet);
        }

        private void close() {
            isSmEnabled = false;
            isOutgoingSmEnabled = false;
            sessionId = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you resolve this ?

Comment: No I didn't, So I just did what yaxim has done. Sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 0):

> when I send the Enable packet to server it says Service
>   Unavailable(503)

Service Unavailable means that the service is unavailable on the server. Does ejabberd support XEP-198? Did you enable it?

You should also consider switching to Smack 4.1.0-alpha, which also runs on Android and comes with Stream Management support. yaxim will soon switch to from it's custom XmppStreamHandler implementation to Smack 4.1.

Comment: Yes ejabberd server supports XEP-198. I checked that using yaxim it worked perfectly.

Comment: hi Flow, I could get the enabled packet from the server. But now, the problem is that I cant send the resume packet to the server. When I send it. Server replies an error saying "unexpected-request". Can you please help me?